# Opposite of (foo|bar|baz)

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like a regex to match everything but a few specific options within a broader expression.

The following example will match test_foo.pl or test_bar.pl or test_baz.pl:

```
/test_(foo|bar|baz)\.pl/
```

But I'd like just the opposite:

```
match test_.*\.pl except for where .* = (foo|bar|baz)
```

I'm kind of limited in my options for this because this is not directly into a perl program, but an argument to [cloc, a program that counts lines of code (that happens to be written in perl)](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/).  So I'm looking for an answer that can be done in one regex, not multiple chained together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by using a negative lookahead:

```
/test_(?!foo|bar|baz).*\.pl/
```

This will fail if `foo`, `bar`, or `baz` immediately follows `test_`.

Note that this could still match something like `test_notfoo.pl`, and would fail on `test_fool.pl`, if you do not want this behavior please clarify by adding some examples of what exactly should and should not match.

If you want to accept something like `test_fool.pl` or `test_bart.pl`, then you could change it to the following:

```
/test_(?!(foo|bar|baz)\.pl).*\.pl/
```

Comment: I think your soution will reject `test_bart.pl`, but as I have understood, the OP will accept `test_bart.pl`, but not `test_bar.pl` (just an example, noting special related to `bart`)

Comment: To make this *only* exclude the givens, you need to match the end of the expression as well: `/test_(?!(foo|bar|baz)\.pl).*\.pl/`. (This version will also be incorrect if the string contains multiple filenames (due to the `.*`), but that shouldn't be the case in the context of the question.)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my $pat = qr/\Atest_.+(?<!foo|bar|baz)[.]pl\z/;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    printf "%s %s\n", $line, $line =~ $pat ? 'matches' : "doesn't match";
}


__DATA__
test_bar.pl
test_foo.pl
test_baz.pl
test baz.pl
0test_bar.pl
test_me.pl
test_me_too.txt
```

Output:

```
test_bar.pl doesn't match
test_foo.pl doesn't match
test_baz.pl doesn't match
test baz.pl doesn't match
0test_bar.pl doesn't match
test_me.pl matches
test_me_too.txt doesn't match
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:(?!STR).)*
```

is to

```
STR
```

as

```
[^CHAR]
```

is to

```
CHAR
```

So you want

```
if (/^test_(?:(?!foo|bar|baz).)*\.pl\z/s)
```

More readable:

```
my %bad = map { $_ => 1 } qw( foo bar baz );

if (/^test_(.*)\.pl\z/s && !$bad{$1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I might have misunderstood your question. Anyway, maybe this is helpful ...

---

You would negate the match operator. For example:

```
perl -lwe "print for grep ! m/(lwp|archive).*\.pl/, glob q(*.pl)"
# Note you'd use single-quotes on Linux but double-quotes on Windows.
# Nothing to do with Perl, just different shells (bash vs cmd.exe).
```

The `!` negates the match. The above is shorthand for:

```
perl -lwe "print for grep ! ($_ =~ m/(lwp|archive).*\.pl/), glob q(*.pl)"
```

Which can also be written using the negated match operator `!~`, as follows:

```
perl -lwe "print for grep $_ !~ m/(lwp|archive).*\.pl/, glob q(*.pl)"
```

In case you're wondering, the [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) is simply used to get an input list of filenames as per your example. I just substituted another match pattern suitable for the files I had handy in a directory.